# jquery - equivalent to Prototype.js' "match" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm upgrading an app from prototype.js to jquery.

I've got this code (prototype.js):

```
var el = ... /* this is done */
if (el.match('.pagination a') && el.href) {
  doAjaxStuff()
}
```

What is the equivalent to [Element.match](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/match) in jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function.

```
el.is('.pagination a')
```